# Django: Adding foreign key to form -> Cannot assign "<SimpleLazyObject:, must be a "User" instance

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

The user is in a DetailView of a patient with a in id (parent table/model), or selects a patient to create a child (table/model) object (I hope that is accurate terminology).
I'm trying to "pre-populate" my form with the correct foreign key from the parent table. Basically, Each patient will have several visits, and the visits need to have the correct foreign key relationships with the patient table ("main" model).

I am getting the following error relating to my `def form_valid` command in the `views.py` file. If I remove this command I get a `not null` error as the field needs to be filled. I also tried `get_instance` function but the forums advise against this in favor of the `def form_valid`.

**Error**

```
Cannot assign "<SimpleLazyObject: 
<django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser object at 0x10d62d278>>": 
"Visit.fk_visit_user" must be a "User" instance.
 Request Method:    POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/clincher/visit/add/2
Django Version: 2.0.4
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:    
Cannot assign "<SimpleLazyObject: <django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser object at 0x10d62d278>>": "Visit.fk_visit_user" must be a "User" instance.
Exception Location: /Users/nrsmoll/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py in __set__, line 197
Python Executable:  /Users/nrsmoll/venv/bin/python
Python Version: 3.6.4
Python Path:    
['/Users/nrsmoll/PycharmProjects/clincher',
 '/Users/nrsmoll/PycharmProjects/clincher',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python36.zip',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
 '/Users/nrsmoll/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages',
 '/Users/nrsmoll/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools-28.8.0-py3.6.egg',
 '/Users/nrsmoll/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py3.6.egg',
 '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pycharm_matplotlib_backend']
Server time:    Wed, 6 Jun 2018 13:16:29 +0000
```

**Traceback**

```
Environment:
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/clincher/visit/add/2

Django Version: 2.0.4
Python Version: 3.6.4
Installed Applications:
['clincher.apps.clincherConfig',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']

Traceback:

File "/Users/nrsmoll/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "/Users/nrsmoll/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Users/nrsmoll/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/Users/nrsmoll/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  69.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/nrsmoll/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  89.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/nrsmoll/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in post
  172.         return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/nrsmoll/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in post
  142.             return self.form_valid(form)

File "/Users/nrsmoll/PycharmProjects/clincher/clincher/views.py" in form_valid
  63.         form.instance.fk_visit_user = self.request.user

File "/Users/nrsmoll/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py" in __set__
  197.                     self.field.remote_field.model._meta.object_name,

Exception Type: ValueError at /clincher/visit/add/2
Exception Value: Cannot assign "<SimpleLazyObject: 
<django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser object at 0x10d62d278>>": 
"Visit.fk_visit_user" must be a "User" instance.
```

**Models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Main(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 256)
    date_of_birth = models.CharField(max_length = 256)
    age = models.CharField(max_length=4)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('clincher:main-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name + ' - ' + self.date_of_birth


class Visit(models.Model):
     fk_visit_main = models.ForeignKey(Main, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name=('Patient Name'))
    visit_date = models.DateField(auto_now = True, editable=True)
    fk_visit_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name=('Practitioner'), max_length=500)

def __str__(self):
    return '%s %s' % (self.visit_date, self.visit_label)

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('clincher:main-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

**Views.py**

```
class VisitCreate(CreateView):
    model = Visit
    fields = [ 'visit_label', 'visit_type', 'visit_progress_notes']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.fk_visit_user = self.request.user **Error Here**
        form.instance.main_id = self.kwargs['pk']
        return super(VisitCreate, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('clincher:main-detail', args={'pk': self.object.id})
```

Basically, I need to have a form that maintains a parent child relationship, if there is a better way, or more efficient way, let me know.

Answer (score 3):

As the error says, you are trying to assign an AnonymousUser to the object. This is because the user accessing your page is not logged in. You need to use the [LoginRequired mixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin) on your view to ensure that they are logged in.

Comment: Ok, that part worked, now I just have a barrier with the next line of code: form.instance.main_id = self.kwargs['pk']. I get a Not Null constraint error, but this is because the "main_id" is incorrect. So I changed it to: form.instance.fk_visit_main (foreign key field), and I get the following error: Cannot assign "2": "Visit.fk_visit_main" must be a "Main" instance. Can you suggest what I do here?